# How to make function of O(n) that checks for letters (upper& lower) & ()+-*/ to a tail recursion?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

I am trying to figure out how do I convert a function I made that checks for the passed string if it only contains letters (lower case or capital) and only these punctuation ()+-*/....to an efficient recursive function, possibly through a tail recursion. Here is my code:

```
/*typedef std::string StringElem;*/
bool verify_input_str(StringElem str_para) {
  for (int x = 0; x < str_para.size(); ++x) {
    if (!(std::isalpha(str_para[x])) && (str_para[x] != '*')&& (str_para[x] != '/')
        && (str_para[x] != '+') && (str_para[x] != '-') && (str_para[x] != ')')
        && (str_para[x] != '(')) {
        return 0;
    }
  }
return 1;
}
```

Could anyone give me a hint, I would really appreciate it. Thanks, looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Possible logic error: I think you meant to use `||` instead of `&&`. Using the latter implies that a char can be both */+- at the same time (maybe in the quantum world?). Actually, I think there's a logic error with the whole loop.  Try passing it `"a1"`.

Comment: @TrebledJ Oh yes, I just figured that too. Let me edit it. I am sorry.

Comment: why do you want to turn it into a recursion? I dont see how a recursion could do better than what you already have in terms of efficiency

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Oh ok, I thought there might be a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since tail recursion requires that there is no computation done after the recursive call, the approach here is pretty straightforward:

- Start with a signature that includes the current position `pos` in `StringElement`
- Check the boundary condition first; if the string is empty, return success
- Next, check the current character; if it is invalid, return failure
- Finally, return the result of calling the function itself with `pos+1`.

**Note:** I am assuming that you are working through a learning exercise on tail recursion, because otherwise a loop-based implementation would be a perfectly good approach.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am doing a book exercise where they asked me to make a loop, and then the next question is to convert it to tail recursion.

Comment: Are tail recursive better than any other simple loop like this?

Comment: @ChoraMora No, they are equivalent. Modern compilers convert functions with tail recursion into loops automatically as part of optimization.

Comment: @ChoraMora the compiler can do transformations of this kind, so it could even be that an iterative and a recursive approach results in the exact same code emitted from the compiler

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 & @ dasblinkenlight thank you so much for sharing your knowledge. I will keep this in mind! Good day to you :)